# Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled

Tags: esp32, rtos, esp-idf

I am trying to run 6 tasks parallel and all the tasks run for infinite time. But when the task starts running this error comes:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400868b4  PS      : 0x00060033  A0      : 0x80085442  A1      : 0x3ffb0b50
0x400868b4: xTaskIncrementTick at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3157

A2      : 0x00000001  A3      : 0x80059301  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000132  
A6      : 0x00000003  A7      : 0x00060023  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffb0b30
A10     : 0x3ffb26b8  A11     : 0x00000003  A12     : 0x00060b20  A13     : 0x00060b23
A14     : 0x3ffb6300  A15     : 0x3ffb53fc  SAR     : 0x00000016  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x80059309  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace:0x400868b1:0x3ffb0b500x4008543f:0x3ffb0b70 0x40085199:0x3ffb0b90 0x400826e9:0x3ffb0ba0 0x400e4b6b:0x3ffb6210 0x400d18ef:0x3ffb6230 0x40086462:0x3ffb6250 0x40087991:0x3ffb6270
0x400868b1: xTaskIncrementTick at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3156

0x4008543f: xPortSysTickHandler at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/port_systick.c:167

0x40085199: _frxt_timer_int at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/portasm.S:329

0x400826e9: _xt_lowint1 at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/xtensa_vectors.S:1111

0x400e4b6b: cpu_ll_waiti at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include/hal/cpu_ll.h:183
 (inlined by) esp_pm_impl_waiti at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/pm_impl.c:837

0x400d18ef: esp_vApplicationIdleHook at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/freertos_hooks.c:63

0x40086462: prvIdleTask at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3973 (discriminator 1)

0x40087991: vPortTaskWrapper at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/port.c:131





ELF file SHA256: 142fe637d0302132

Rebooting...
```

Comment: Hi preetjhota, welcome to SO. We can't help without your code. Please update your post to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: And also, you are probably starving the tasks. Try to yield them more frequently. `_frxt_timer_int` tells me the scheduler is struggling to balance them all.

Add some `xTaskDelay` on the tasks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72796983/guru-meditation-error-core-0-paniced-loadprohibited)

Comment: Yes, I will update accordingly.