# Guru Meditation Error: Core 0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited)

Tags: esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I am trying to run 6 tasks parallel and all the tasks run for infinite time. But when the task starts running this error comes:

```
Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (LoadProhibited). Exception was unhandled.

Core  0 register dump:
PC      : 0x400868b4  PS      : 0x00060033  A0      : 0x80085442  A1      : 0x3ffb0b50
0x400868b4: xTaskIncrementTick at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3157

A2      : 0x00000001  A3      : 0x80059301  A4      : 0x00000000  A5      : 0x00000132  
A6      : 0x00000003  A7      : 0x00060023  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x3ffb0b30
A10     : 0x3ffb26b8  A11     : 0x00000003  A12     : 0x00060b20  A13     : 0x00060b23
A14     : 0x3ffb6300  A15     : 0x3ffb53fc  SAR     : 0x00000016  EXCCAUSE: 0x0000001c
EXCVADDR: 0x80059309  LBEG    : 0x00000000  LEND    : 0x00000000  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  


Backtrace:0x400868b1:0x3ffb0b500x4008543f:0x3ffb0b70 0x40085199:0x3ffb0b90 0x400826e9:0x3ffb0ba0 0x400e4b6b:0x3ffb6210 0x400d18ef:0x3ffb6230 0x40086462:0x3ffb6250 0x40087991:0x3ffb6270
0x400868b1: xTaskIncrementTick at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3156
0x4008543f: xPortSysTickHandler at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/port_systick.c:167
0x40085199: _frxt_timer_int at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/portasm.S:329
0x400826e9: _xt_lowint1 at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/xtensa_vectors.S:1111
0x400e4b6b: cpu_ll_waiti at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/hal/esp32/include/hal/cpu_ll.h:183
 (inlined by) esp_pm_impl_waiti at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_pm/pm_impl.c:837
0x400d18ef: esp_vApplicationIdleHook at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/esp_system/freertos_hooks.c:63

0x40086462: prvIdleTask at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/tasks.c:3973 (discriminator 1)
0x40087991: vPortTaskWrapper at C:/Users/preet/esp/esp-idf/components/freertos/port/xtensa/port.c:131
ELF file SHA256: 142fe637d0302132
Rebooting...
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/semphr.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "sdkconfig.h"
#define TAG "Smart Sliding Gate"
#define PUSH_BUTTON 25
#define FORCE_STOP_BUTTON 26
#define IR_PIN 14
#define RELAY_1_PIN 22
#define RELAY_2_PIN 21
#define MAGNET_1_PIN 12
#define MAGNET_2_PIN 13
TaskHandle_t FFO_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t FRO_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t MS_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t MFS_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t MRS_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t IR_xHandle = NULL;
TaskHandle_t MAGNET_xHandle = NULL;
int MOTOR_STATE = 0;
xSemaphoreHandle I_F_F_O_SIGNAL = 0;
xSemaphoreHandle M_F_F_O_SIGNAL = 0;
xSemaphoreHandle M_F_R_O_SIGNAL = 0;
void MOTOR_FORWARD_START(void * pvParameters)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_1_PIN);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_2_PIN);

    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_1_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_2_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    gpio_set_level(RELAY_1_PIN, 1);
    gpio_set_level(RELAY_2_PIN, 0);
    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor working in forward direction.");

    vTaskDelete(MFS_xHandle);
}
void MOTOR_REVERSE_START(void * pvParameters)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_1_PIN);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_2_PIN);

    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_1_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_2_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    
    gpio_set_level(RELAY_1_PIN, 0);
    gpio_set_level(RELAY_2_PIN, 1);
    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor working in reverse direction.");

    vTaskDelete(MRS_xHandle);
}
void MOTOR_STOP(void * pvParameters)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_1_PIN);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(RELAY_2_PIN);

    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_1_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(RELAY_2_PIN, GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT);

    gpio_set_level(RELAY_1_PIN, 0);
    gpio_set_level(RELAY_2_PIN, 0);
    ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor Stopped.");

    vTaskDelete(MS_xHandle);
}
void MAGNETIC_END_SENSOR()
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(MAGNET_1_PIN);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(MAGNET_2_PIN);

    gpio_set_direction(MAGNET_1_PIN, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(MAGNET_2_PIN, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);

    while (1)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(MAGNET_1_PIN) == 1 || gpio_get_level(MAGNET_2_PIN) == 1){
            if (MOTOR_STATE == 0){
                xSemaphoreGive(M_F_F_O_SIGNAL);
                ESP_LOGW(TAG, "F Signal sent.");
            }
            else if (MOTOR_STATE == 1){
                xSemaphoreGive(M_F_R_O_SIGNAL);
                ESP_LOGW(TAG, "R Signal sent.");
            }
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Gate reached to the destination, Stopping the motor.");
            xTaskCreate(&MOTOR_STOP, "MOTOR_STOP", 512, NULL, 1, MS_xHandle);
            MOTOR_STATE =! MOTOR_STATE;
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor stopped and Motor State changed.");
            vTaskDelete(MAGNET_xHandle);
        }
    }
}
void FULL_REVERSE_OPERATION(void * pvParameters)
{
    xTaskCreate(&MOTOR_REVERSE_START, "MOTOR_REVERSE_START", 512, NULL, 1, MRS_xHandle);
    vTaskDelay( 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS );
    xTaskCreate(&MAGNETIC_END_SENSOR, "MAGNETIC_END_SENSOR", 1024, NULL, 1, MAGNET_xHandle);

    while (1)
    {
        if (xSemaphoreTake(M_F_R_O_SIGNAL, portMAX_DELAY)){
            vTaskDelete(FRO_xHandle);
        }
    }
}
void IR_INTERRUPT_SENSOR(void * pvParameters)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(IR_PIN);
    gpio_set_direction(IR_PIN, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    while (1)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(IR_PIN) == 0){
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "IR Rays Intreupted.");
            xSemaphoreGive(I_F_F_O_SIGNAL);
            xTaskCreate(&MOTOR_STOP, "MOTOR_STOP", 512, NULL, 1, MS_xHandle);
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor Stopped.");
            MOTOR_STATE =! MOTOR_STATE;
            xTaskCreate(&FULL_REVERSE_OPERATION, "FULL_REVERSE_OPERATION", 1536, NULL, 1, MRS_xHandle);
            ESP_LOGW(TAG, "Motor State changed and working in reverse direction.");
            vTaskDelete(IR_xHandle);
        }
    }
}
void FULL_FORWARD_OPERTAION(void * pvParameters)
{
    xTaskCreate(&MOTOR_FORWARD_START, "MOTOR_FORWARD_START", 1024, NULL, 1, MFS_xHandle);
    xTaskCreate(&IR_INTERRUPT_SENSOR, "IR_INTERRUPT_SENSOR", 2048, NULL, 1, IR_xHandle);
    vTaskDelay( 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS );
    xTaskCreate(&MAGNETIC_END_SENSOR, "MAGNETIC_END_SENSOR", 1536, NULL, 1, MAGNET_xHandle);
    while (1)
    {
        if (xSemaphoreTake(I_F_F_O_SIGNAL, portMAX_DELAY)){
            vTaskDelete(MAGNET_xHandle);
            vTaskDelete(FFO_xHandle);
        }
        else if (xSemaphoreTake(M_F_F_O_SIGNAL, portMAX_DELAY)){
            vTaskDelete(IR_xHandle);
            vTaskDelete(FFO_xHandle);
        } 
    }   
}
void BUTTON_OPERATION(void * pvParameters)
{
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(PUSH_BUTTON);
    gpio_pad_select_gpio(FORCE_STOP_BUTTON);
    gpio_set_direction(PUSH_BUTTON, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    gpio_set_direction(FORCE_STOP_BUTTON, GPIO_MODE_INPUT);
    while (1)
    {
        if (gpio_get_level(PUSH_BUTTON) == 1){
            if (MOTOR_STATE == 0){
                xTaskCreate(&FULL_FORWARD_OPERTAION, "FULL_FORWARD_OPERTAION", 4096, NULL, 1, FFO_xHandle);
            }
            else if (MOTOR_STATE == 1){
                xTaskCreate(&FULL_REVERSE_OPERATION, "FULL_REVERSE_OPERATION", 1536, NULL, 1, FRO_xHandle);
            }
        }
        else if (gpio_get_level(FORCE_STOP_BUTTON) == 1){
            xTaskCreate(&MOTOR_STOP, "MOTOR_STOP", 512, NULL, 1, MS_xHandle);
        }
        vTaskDelay( 500 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS );
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    vSemaphoreCreateBinary(I_F_F_O_SIGNAL);
    vSemaphoreCreateBinary(M_F_F_O_SIGNAL);
    vSemaphoreCreateBinary(M_F_R_O_SIGNAL);
    xTaskCreate(&BUTTON_OPERATION, "BUTTON_OPERATION", 4096, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY, NULL);
}
```

Comment: A good first thing to try, is to keep track of the assigned stack per task. Is it starved? And maybe it’s possible to combine tasks.

Comment: You design is problematic. I'd not recommend creating/deleting tasks for every single action (and also without any synchronization/check if one of those tasks is already/still running).

Comment: I don't see evidence that "_all the tasks run for infinite time_" - there are numerous task deletions and ill-advised global variables.  You appear to be trying to do the task  scheduler's job for it and entirely missed the point of an RTOS.  Typically all threads will be indefinite loops that block on some IPC or Synchronisation mechanism  or RTOS delay and are triggered by other threads triggering  that mechanism, or the delay period expiring.  You would not normally delete a task on completion; you'd simply loop back to the blocking call and wait for the next triggering event.

Answer (score 0):

This error also occurs when one includes a `.h` file multiple times.